# How to validate all controller before button call OnClientClick javascript event?

Tags: asp.net

When btnSave Clicked, it will call function check().

If check() return true, the page will postback and call the btnSave_Click event.

But I think it should be check the RequiredFieldValidator first before it call fucntion check().

How can I fix it?

> In Default.aspx

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.vb" Inherits="TestValidation._Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function check() {
        return confirm("Real?");
    }

</script>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" />
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="TextBox1" Display="Dynamic" ValidationGroup="vldGrp">AA</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
        <asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" ValidationGroup="vldGrp" Text="Save" OnClientClick="return check();" />
        <asp:ValidationSummary ID="vldSum" runat="server" DisplayMode="List" ShowSummary="False" ValidationGroup="vldGrp" ShowMessageBox="True" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

> In Default.aspx.vb

```
Partial Public Class _Default
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    End Sub


    Private Sub btnSave_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSave.Click

    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check for the required field validator inside the function first and then perform the operations inside the function as:

```
function check() {
    var validation = <%= RequiredFieldValidator1.ClientID %>;
    if(validation.isValid()){
        return confirm("Real?");
    }
}
```

If there are many required field validators, and you need to invoke all of those, try:

```
function check() {
    if (Page_ClientValidate()) {
        return confirm("Real?");
    }
}
```

Or even based on the name of your ValidationGroup (incase you need to invoke only selected validators)

```
function check() {
    if (Page_ClientValidate('your group name')) {
        return confirm("Real?");
    }
}
```

Or else you can also check for the validation on server side,

```
Sub ValidateBtn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Page.Validate()
    If (Page.IsValid) Then
        DoSomething()
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I prefer use solution case 1 but, there are lots of RequiredFieldValidator controllers. How can I do?

Comment: If you need to check for all the validations in the page, try if (Page_ClientValidate()) { } instead.